# The SSL tab on MAMP PRO is greyed out

Tags: ssl, https, mamp

I'm trying to set up HTTPS on my MAMP localhost server. I've followed a number of tutorials telling me to change things in `httpd.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf`, but to no avail. I had a look through MAMP and found the SSL tab, which looks like it should be able to automatically generate a certificate and set it all up for me.

As you can see in the picture below, the SSL checkbox is greyed out, and the buttons in the SSL tab are greyed out too and don't do anything.

[image: SSL tab is greyed out]

Is there any way I can un-grey-out the SSL tab, or if not (well, there must be,) is there anything else I could try to get HTTPS working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL is not available on default localhost in MAMP Pro. Make a new host with a custom name like yoursite.dev and you'll be able to active SSL.

**Update 2019**
Since you can now buy .dev domains, you should use something else like yoursite.local to avoid conflicts or unexpected behavior.